# Quickbooks Customers with accented characters being mutated on upload

Tags: unicode, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am having troubles with adding a customer with accent characters. The submitted characters are not being stored in QB as I would expect and, of course, this causes problems with the originating application. Here is an example of a customer ADD request and the response. Please note the differences in the name ... División vs Divisiýn The latter is what is being stored in QuickBooks. I am using the QB On-Line Edition version 6.0 SDK.

```
 #### REQUEST PORTION ####
 <?xml  version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
 <?qbxml version="6.0"?>
 <QBXML><QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
 <CustomerAddRq requestID="7770">
 <CustomerAdd><Name>Codelco División Ministro Hales</Name>

 #### RESPONSE PORTION ####
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
 <!DOCTYPE QBXML PUBLIC "-//INTUIT//DTD QBXML QBO 6.0//EN" "http://apps.quickbooks.com/dtds/qbxmlops60.dtd">
 ....
 <CustomerAddRs requestID="7770" statusCode="0" statusMessage="Status OK" statusSeverity="Info">
    <CustomerRet>
     ....
     <Name>Codelco Divisiýn Ministro Hales</Name>
```

Thanks

Comment: The terminology for characters with accents is Unicode. Apparently, [QuickBooks support](http://community.intuit.com/tags/unicode) for Unicode has caused some people problems.

Comment: The request looks valid and works on QB2013 Enterprise.  You should include what version of QB you are trying to work with.

Comment: To cut-and-paste your code, put it in an ascii file, and insert 4 or 5 leading space characters (0x20) in the start of each line. You can paste that and it should give you a source code insert in your post.

Comment: Thanks User.1, I edited the post to include the XML

Comment: William, I edited to post to include the QB version and SDK.

Comment: @Mike: Have you verified that it is in fact a storage issue and not simply a display issue? If it is just a display issue then additional otions fo rhanding this might exist.

Comment: Pieter, I am not sure how I could verify that since I have no way of looking at the underlying database. In QBOE the customer is displayed with "Divisiýn". When I make a request for the customer from my app, I get "Divisiýn". So I am assuming that it is stored as that character in their database.

Comment: How are you generating your XML request? Is it possible that your string is defaulting to UTF-16 in your code but you are instructing the XML processor to read it as ISO-8859?

Comment: I do generate the xml using Java's DocumentBuilder class and POST it to the QBOE server using the apache HttpClient. As a test, I wrote out the MultipartEntity just before sending it and found the results to be what I expected. I am now thinking I need to get a packet sniffer and examine what is actually getting sent to get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 3):

Two things you can try:

- What happens if you use the entity &oacute; instead of ó directly?
- Have you tried using UTF-8 as the encoding? In the XML world it's used more often and UTF-8 allows for many more characters, accented or otherwise.

Two things that might be happening at the server side, which you might not be able to determine:

- Is the server configured for another ISO-8859 standard? (e.g. -4 onwards have different characters for character 243).
- Are you sure ý is being saved in QB, or could it be y followed by a combining ´ accent?

/YR

Comment: How would I determine if the server is configured with another ISO-8859? It is a Windows Server 2008.

Comment: I'd suggest `&#F3;` in an XML document, in case the DTD doesn't define `oacute`.

Comment: I have generated xml that uses three different ways to define the accented characters.

Codelco Divisi&amp;oacute;n Ministro Hales
Codelco Divisi&amp;#243;n Ministro Hales
Codelco División Ministro Hales

The 1st two are received by QBOE literally (with the &...) while the last one is transposed from División to Divisiýn.

I have not tried using UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-1, although I probably will just to not leave any suggestion untried.

Comment: I changed the encoding to UTF-8. The results were identical to ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Looks like an issue at the server side. You're doing everything right. I'd let them know they have some issues with respect to handling accented characters. As others have pointed out, it's  a known problem and later versions have fixed it.